# ASPNET MVC 3 Ajax.BeginForm not working with Chrome nor Firefox. Works with IE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a partial view which contains two other partial views. The containing ones have something like this

```
<div id="divCIContent" class="rcol-box">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveCI", "MyController", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "divCIContent"
}, new { id = "ajaxFormCI" }))
```

and this inside the form

```
<button type="submit" class="my-save">Save</button></li>
```

En Save button is clicked the controller should save the form values anda return another partial view as PartialViewResult.

The problem is that in Chrome and Firefox it's making a full postback, and the result is seen in a blank new page, instead inside the _Layout. In IE it works ok.

On the controller method I can see that Request.IsAjaxRequest returns false for Chrome and Firefox true for IE. No errors seen in Fiddler nor Firebug or Chrome debug tools.

I've the webconfig keys set

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

and I'm using unbstrusive jquery ajax files.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: I cannot recreate this problem using Chrome.  Please edit your questino, and add the main view and the partial views.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was that we had nested forms (one in the main page containing the PartialViews and one inside each PartialView. When we removed the form in the main page, it started to work.
Thanks! Guillermo.